# Exclude folder from download git

Tags: git

I'd like to include all folders from my local project in the bare repo (bitbucket) but exclude one directory from the fetch/merge/download.

E.g. I'd like to exclude directory b from being downloaded to my remote

```
local
  /project
    /a
    /b
    /c

bare
  /project
    /a
    /b
    /c

remote
  /project
    /a
    /c
```

Is there a way of doing this without having to do some kind of deletion after download on my remote?

Comment: That's not something that Git generally does. What does directory `b/` contain? There may be a better solution. You might also want to read up on [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It's a question of reliable ssh/deployment to ec2.  b contains too much data to transfer and then delete.  I've tried rsync, but I'm not as confident in it as git... I'm thinking svn maybe at this point..

Comment: "b contains too much data to transfer and then delete." Why do you want to delete it in the first place? I'll ask again: _What does the directory contain?_ (Note also that Git isn't a deployment tool.)

Comment: Well, tell that to Heroku, etc. ... b contains code unnecessary for running the server.

Comment: Bryan, I really wish you would tell us what `b/` _actually contains_. Documentation? Database dumps? Maybe the best solution is to exclude that from Git entirely. Or to put it in a separate repository. Or any number of other things. But since you insist on telling us what it isn't instead of what it is we can't explore those options with you. That makes it exceedingly difficult to find a good solution.

Comment: @Chris Folder 'b/' is a hypothetical.  The question is how do you move only part of a folder over a network.  With Git?  With another non-deployment tool?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it.

The only thing you can do it to checkout the folder, delete it manually or with smudge/clean and than mark it as `git update-index assume-unchanged` so git will not track the changes you made in there.

#### --[no-]assume-unchanged

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>
> Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a file system that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.